# Facebook Login custom UI button for web

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, facebook-login

Is it possible to customize Facebook Login button?, actually i tried for Facebook login plugins from "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button", but here some standard login buttons only available.

If possible to customize, i want to customize login button dimensions and font size, i hope to get answer for this question.

Html code:

```
<fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: if you're using jquery, and are happy to use it, it should be possible to 'manipulate it' based on your requirements..

Comment: yes, i am using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesnt allow customizing the buttons.It uses fbml.

From their doc

```
Unfortunately, it’s against Facebook’s developer policies, which state

You must not circumvent our intended limitations on core Facebook features.

The Facebook Connect button is intended to be rendered in FBML, which means it’s only meant to look the way Facebook lets it.
```

But i have seen some customisation made for the login button [here](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/customising-facebook-connect-s-fb-login-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple html button and style it the way you want, and use the [facebook javascript api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2) to launch the login yourself